# Pasar una tabla de wikipedia a csv en python

Tags: python

No he podido hacer que la tabla se vea como un archivo csv, lo que pasa es que cuando se guarda en el archivo csv aparece con espacios y quiero que se vea todo junto.

Este es mi codigo

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata =BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

playerdatasaved = ""
soup = make_soup("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Holloway")
for record in soup.findAll("tr"):
    playerdata = ""
    for data in record.findAll("td"):
        playerdata=playerdata + "," + data.text
    if len(playerdata) !=0:
        playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[0:]

header = "Resultado, Record, Oponente, Método, Evento, Fecha, Ronda, Tiempo, Localizacion, Notas" 
file =open(os.path.expanduser("max_holloway.csv"), "wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding= "ascii", errors="ignore"))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved, encoding= "ascii", errors="ignore"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer data.txt viene con un "\r\n" al final. La solución es eliminar ese caracter.

Modifique sólo estas líneas del código original

```
for data in record.findAll("td"):
    playerdata=playerdata + "," + data.text
if len(playerdata) !=0:
    playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[0:]
```

Reemplazandolas por

```
for data in record.findAll("td"):
    playerdata=playerdata + "," + data.text.strip() 
if len(playerdata) !=0:
    playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]
```

para eliminar las "\r\n" y las "," extras de la línea en construcción.

También cambie la codificación a UTF8 en los `write`. De otra manera, se pierden los caracteres con acentos.

```
file.write(bytes(header, encoding= "utf8", errors="ignore"))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved, encoding= "utf8", errors="ignore"))
```

Con esas modificaciones, el còdigo que asi:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata =BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

playerdatasaved = ""
soup = make_soup("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Holloway")
for record in soup.findAll("tr"):
    playerdata = ""
    for data in record.findAll("td"):
        playerdata=playerdata + "," + data.text.strip() 
    if len(playerdata) !=0:
        playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]

header = "Resultado, Record, Oponente, Método, Evento, Fecha, Ronda, Tiempo, Localizacion, Notas" 
file =open(os.path.expanduser("max_holloway.csv"), "wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding= "utf8", errors="ignore"))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved, encoding= "utf8", errors="ignore"))
```

lo que produce

```
Resultado, Record, Oponente, Método, Evento, Fecha, Ronda, Tiempo, Localizacion, Notas

Jerome-Max Holloway
4 de diciembre de 1991 (28 años)Waianae, Hawái,  Estados Unidos
Blessed
Kickboxing
Gracie Technics
70 kg (154 lb)
1,80 m (5 ft 11 in)
Estadounidense
2010-presente
27
21
10
2
9
6
1
5
[editar datos en Wikidata]
Derrota,21–6,Alexander Volkanovski,Decisión (dividida),UFC 251,11 de julio de 2020,5,5:00,Abu Dab
i,Por el Campeonato de Peso Pluma de UFC.
Derrota,21–5,Alexander Volkanovski,Decisión (unánime),UFC 245,14 de diciembre de 2019,5,5:00,Para
dise, Nevada,Perdió el Campeonato de Peso Pluma de UFC.
Victoria,21–4,Frankie Edgar,Decisión (unánime),UFC 240,27 de julio de 2019,5,5:00,Edmonton, Alber
ta,Defendió el Campeonato de Peso Pluma de UFC.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvio